# Cannot create dictionary with tuples and values? (list indices must be integers, not str)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
q_values_table = {}
light = ['red', 'green']
v_actions = ['None','forward','left','right']


for i in v_actions:
    for j in light:
        for k in v_actions:
            for l in v_actions:
                for m in v_actions:
                    q_values_table[v_actions[i],light[j],v_actions[k],v_actions[l],v_actions[m]] = None

print q_values_table
```

I want my output be like `{('right','red','forward','right','left') : None}` 
for all the values.

But I'm getting this error `list indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate a `list`, you get values, not indices. If you want indices, use `range`:

```
for i in range(len(v_actions)):
    ...
```

If you want indices and values, use `enumerate`:

```
for i, value in enumerate(v_actions):
    ...
```

As it stands, you are attempt to access list elements using strings that are contained in the list as an index.

Answer (score 1):

just replace the last line with:

`q_values_table[ i, j, k, l, m ] = None`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use range(len(lst)) to just iterate over the indices of the list:

```
q_values_table = {}
light = ['red', 'green']
v_actions = ['None','forward','left','right']
for i in range(len(v_actions)):
    for j in range(len(light)):
        for k in range(len(v_actions)):
            for l in range(len(v_actions)):
                for m in range(len(v_actions)):
                    q_values_table[v_actions[i],light[j],v_actions[k],v_actions[l],v_actions[m]] = None

print q_values_table
```

This is a bit more verbose than the other options presented but seems to be what you were intending to do: iterate over the indices of a list.